# Geometry behind glass material appears slanted in render

Tags: rendering

When I render an image, there are bevels somewhere on it that shouldn't be there.[image] [image]How to fix it?

Comment: It almost appears like it's index of refraction hitting the hard normals of triangulated geometry. Have you tried rendering with glass set to auto smooth? Turn the glass object off during render and see if distortion occurs? Give the glass a shiny reflective MatCap material and check if normals reflect oddly?

Comment: @CobyRandal yes, without glass all is fine, i added modifer and the problem desapiar, thanks

Comment: @CobyRandal Form it as a response so I can mark it as a solution

Comment: Ok will do! What modifier did you add that worked for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It almost appears like it's index of refraction hitting the hard normals of triangulated geometry. Have you tried rendering with glass set to auto smooth (Object Data Properties>Normals>Auto Smooth)? Turn the glass object off during render and see if distortion occurs. Give the glass a shiny reflective MatCap material and check if normals reflect oddly. Some modifiers that can help (depending on if you want sharp or smooth glass): 1. Weighted Normal 2. Edge Split. You typically use them separately.